# Separating Values from a file in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, input

So let's say I have this txt file formatted (value)(space)(value) and there's a second set of numbers separated with a (tab). An example file is given here:

```
Header
5 5 6 7 8   7 8 9 0 1
7 6 3 4 1   1 3 6 8 1
8 7 4 1 3   1 9 8 5 1
```

Now I'm using this code to print all the values shown in the txt file:

```
NEWLINE = "\n"

def readBoardFromFile():
    inputFileOK = False
    aBoard = []

    while (inputFileOK == False):
        try:
            inputFileName = input("Enter the name of your file: ")
            inputFile = open(inputFileName, "r")
            print("Opening File " + inputFileName + "for reading")

            currentRow = 0
            next(inputFile)

            for line in inputFile:
                aBoard.append([])

                for ch in line:
                    if (ch != NEWLINE):
                        aBoard[currentRow].append(ch)

                currentRow = currentRow + 1

            inputFileOK = True
            print("Completed reading of file " + inputFileName)

        except IOError:
            print("Error: File couldn't be opened")

    numRows = len(aBoard)
    numColumns = len(aBoard[0])

    return(aBoard,numRows,numColumns)

def display(aBoard, numRows, numColumns):

    currentRow = 0
    currentColumn = 0
    print("DISPLAY")

    while (currentRow < numRows):
        currentColumn = 0
        while (currentColumn < numColumns):
            print("%s" %(aBoard[currentRow][currentColumn]), end="")
            currentColumn = currentColumn + 1
        currentRow = currentRow + 1
        print()

    for currentColumn in range (0,numColumns,1):
        print("*", end ="")

    print(NEWLINE)

def start():
    aBoard,numRows,numColumns = readBoardFromFile()
    display(aBoard,numRows,numColumns)



start()
```

Normally when I run this code this is the output:

```
DISPLAY
5 5 6 7 8       7 8 9 0 1
7 6 3 4 1       1 3 6 8 1
8 7 4 1 3       1 9 8 5 1
*******************
```

How do I make it so that the output is:

```
DISPLAY
5 5 6 7 8       
7 6 3 4 1       
8 7 4 1 3
```

Only displaying the numbers in the left half?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try using the csv module and open the file with tab delimiter.
Then assuming you go with the list approach you could only print the first element from each row.

Something like:

```
import csv
with open("a.txt") as my_file:

    reader = csv.reader(my_file, delimiter ='\t')

    next(reader) # to skip header if exists
    for line in reader:
        print(line[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you aren't taking the tab character into account in your code which is probably why you have the additional characters in your output.

Here's the approach I would take, utilising Python's power when it comes to processing strings.

I would encourage you to use this type of approach when writing Python, as it will make your like much easier.

```py
NEWLINE = "\n"

def read_board_from_file():
    input_file_OK = False
    a_board = []

    while not input_file_OK:
        try:
            input_file_name = input("Enter the name of your file: ")

            with open(input_file_name, "r") as input_file:
                # A file-like object (as returned by open())
                # can be simply iterated 
                for line in input_file:

                    # Skip header line if present
                    # (not sure how you would want to handle the
                    # header.
                    if "header" in line.lower():
                        continue

                    # Strip NEWLINE from each line,
                    # then split the line at the tab character.
                    # See comment above.
                    parts = line.strip(NEWLINE).split("\t")

                    # parts is a list, we are only interested
                    # in the first bit.
                    first_part = parts[0]

                    # Split the left part at all whitespaces.
                    # I'm assuming that this is what you want.
                    # A more complex treatment might make sense here,
                    # depending on your use-case.
                    entries = first_part.split()

                    # entries is a list, so we just need to append it
                    # to the board
                    a_board.append(entries)

            input_file_OK = True
            print(f"Completed reading of file {input_file_name}")

        except IOError:
            print("Error: File {input_file_name} couldn't be opened.")

    return a_board

def display_board(a_board):
    print("DISPLAY")

    longest_row = 0

    # a_board is a list of lists,
    # no need to keep track of the number of rows and columns,
    # we can just iterate it.
    for row in a_board:
        # row is a list of entries, we can use str.join() to add a space
        # between the parts and format the row nicely.
        row_str = " ".join(row)

        # At the same time we can keep track of the longest row
        # for printing the footer later.
        len_row_str = len(row_str)
        if len_row_str > longest_row:
            longest_row = len_row_str

        print(row_str)

    # The footer is simply the asterisk character
    # printed as many times as the longest row.
    footer = "*" * longest_row
    print(footer, end="")

    print(NEWLINE)

def start():
    a_board = read_board_from_file()

    display_board(a_board)

start()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this with a bit more separation between inputs, outputs, and data processing. Your input is the name of the file, and a secondary input is the actual file contents. The data processing step is taking the file contents, and returning some internal representation of a collection of boards. The output is displaying the first board.

```
from typing import Iterable, List

def parse(lines: Iterable[str], board_sep: str = "\t") -> List[List[List[str]]]:
    boards = []
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        # list of the same line from each board
        board_lines = line.split(board_sep)
        if i == 0:
            # this only happens once at the start
            # each board can be a list of lists. so boards is a list of "list of lists"
            # we're going to append lines to each board, so we need some initial setup
            # of boards
            boards = [[] for _ in range(len(board_lines))]

        for board_idx, board_line in enumerate(board_lines):
            # then just add each line of each board to the corresponding section
            boards[board_idx].append(board_line.split())
    return boards


def show_board(board: List[List[str]]) -> None:
    for row in board:
        print(" ".join(row))
```

Now we can put that all together. We need to:

1. Get the filename
2. Open the file
3. Filter out the "Header" and any blank lines
4. Pass the rest of the lines to the `parse()` function
5. Get the first board
6. Print it with the context

```
from typing import Tuple

def get_board_dimensions(board: List[List[str]]) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    """ Returns a tuple of (rows, cols) """
    return len(board), len(board[0])


def get_filtered_file(filename: str) -> Iterable[str]:
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            if not line or line.lower() == "header":
                continue
            yield line


def main():
    filename = input("Enter the name of your file: ")
    filtered_lines = get_filtered_file(filename)
    boards = parse(filtered_lines)

    # now we can show the first one
    b = boards[0]
    _, cols = get_board_dimensions(b)
    print("DISPLAY")
    show_board(b)
    print("*" * (2 * cols - 1))  # columns plus gaps
```